# Ошибка KeyError в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pandas, telegram, telebot

Всем привет! Очень нужен взгляд со стороны, я более чем уверен что ошибка максимально банальная. Пытаюсь сделать для работы чуть более удобное расписание через тг бота. Ниже будет проблемная часть кода. Суть вообще данного фрагмента - имея дф из pandas найти ячейки где есть имя работника и выслать сообщением адрес точки и день недели когда он работает. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь ибо я уже теряю надежду на эту затею. На скрине прикладываю что отображается при нажатии на кнопку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Я студент 2 курса строительного университета, так что простите меня если вам покажется что я какие-то вещи делаю не правильно или можно было бы намного проще, для меня это просто хобби и я хочу и буду развиваться в дальнейшем. В общем не судите строго.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback:True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'show_my_shedule':
        global MY_SHEDULE
        global worker
        my_shedule = ''
        rows = df.shape[0]
        columns = df.shape[1]
        for i in range(columns):
            for j in range(rows):
                if worker in df.iloc[i,j]:
                    day = day_dictionary[i]
                    location = location_dictionary[j]
                    my_shedule= my_shedule + day + ',' + location + ' '
        MY_SHEDULE = f'{worker}, твои рабочие дни: {my_shedule}'
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, MY_SHEDULE)
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже еше изучаю питон, но судя по ошибке:
у тебя в словаре "day_dictionary" нет ключа "i"
попробуй включить отладку и узнать что находится внутри "i" в каждый момент
"day = day_dictionary[i]"